# SQLite database is not responding while executing a JAR

Tags: hibernate, sqlite, executable-jar

I have a spring boot application with SQLite3 database, that I need to convert into a JAR and run it. But the problem which I am facing  while running the JAR  is values are not going to update into the SQLite DB.  I thought it may be a code issue but when debugging or running the Spring Boot app values were updated successfully.  I am not understanding the problem with the JAR.

I thought like while running the JAR may be it is lossing the connection with db. I have used `entitymanager.isOpen()` method to check the db connection and it is returning the true.

```
@Transactional()
public FileTransferStatusDetailsEntity saveFileTransferStatusDetails(
            FileTransferStatusDetailsEntity fileTransferStatusDetailsEntity) {

        logger.info(" FileTransferStatusDetailsRepositoryImpl.saveFileTransferStatusDetails()");
        try {


            fileTransferStatusDetailsEntity = entityManager.merge(fileTransferStatusDetailsEntity);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception  saveFileTransferStatusDetails() in  FileTransferStatusDetailsRepositoryImpl:"
                    + ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
        } finally {
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.clear();
        }
        return fileTransferStatusDetailsEntity;

    }
```

It got stuck at `entityManager.merge(entity)` method.

Comment: Can you please show the datasource url

Comment: driverClassName = org.sqlite.JDBC
url = jdbc:sqlite:mydatabase.db

Comment: Have you tried to set the URL to a fix path?

Comment: yes the db is created. Some values are also inserted  into the table but unable to update.

Comment: So the code hangs on the line where you call merge?

Comment: yes .. only while running the jar

Comment: And why do you know that's on the line with merge? Did you debug it?

Comment: sorry @SimonMartinelli for misunderstanding. I put the logger before and after merge method. It is working fine. I put the same thing to flush method and it prints before flush and after flush it is not at all printing, may be the flush is causing the problem

Comment: Sure flush is executing the SQL statements. Don't you see any exception?

Comment: It is not throwing any kind of exceptions.

Comment: I've been having problems similar to this. It seems to be related to the fact that SQLite is single threaded. Been tweaking the config and moved to c3p0 - but it is still very very dodgy...